# Unmanaged code in .Net

Tags: c#, visual-c++, winforms-interop

We have a custom Listview Treegrid in c++ project built on the Codeproject TreeGrid example from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68/SuperGrid-Yet-Another-listview-control).  The code has been modified quite extensively over time.

I have a requirement to port the c++ project to C# Winforms.  I'm thinking of creating a c++ dll for the Listview grid and interoperate with it in Winforms.

Am I asking for for trouble using an unmanaged Listview control in Winforms?  Should I just port/rewrite the listview in Winforms? (A task I do not look forward too)

Comment: I would think if somebody asked you to port from C++ to C# they probably don't want native code in the ported version.

Comment: The only requirement is to get the look and feel into the Winforms app.  I am exploring options of how to do that now.

Comment: Not too familiar with that how would it work?  Would I still need a dll?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about it. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would prefer rewriting the Listview in C# or looking for a free or paid Grid that was written in C# and is meant to be used in Winforms.

Don't forget that you will have to support the code after you do this job,
this probably includes fixing bugs and adding features.
It's better to know exactly how your code works and how to debug it.
You also gives you a chance to write a Listview that is better suited for your needs.

This will be quite difficult if you'll use this C++ Listview and use it in Winforms.
But if you decide using it, there are two options that I can think of:

1. Creating a wrapper for the Listview in C++/CLI that will hold the object and show the data in C#, this means that you will have to write a lot of conversion code to move the data from the Listview to the C# objects, but it should work.
2. Using DllImport and working with the ListView as a datasource, I'm not really sure how exactly you will be able to get all the data from it, but it prevents you from writing the ugly CLI code...

So to wrap it up, I recommend using a single language for UI code, and my language of choice for UI is C#, not C++.

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks Shahar...I'm beginning to see what a mess keeping the c++ version around would be.  Unless I can find a free/paid grid I will port.  I'm giving you the check for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to re-write it in managed code.

Interoperability usually works, but there's a reason managed code is preferred.  The runtime takes care of so many things for you, and it's just easier to maintain all around. Crossing the boundary can be problematic for some tasks.  You also lose Code Access Security, for example.  There's some good info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx#manunman_topic6).

If you don't then you'll always need a .NET developer and a c++ developer to maintain it.

There's nothing wrong with c++/native code on its own, but mixing the two. I just think it's better long term not to mix unless you have to.

That said, there are time and budgetary constraints.  Interop exists for a reason.  If it would absolutely take too long to justify from a business sense, I'd retract the above recommendation.

Comment: I see what you mean with all the marshalling/clean up code that would be necessary.  The only reason I considered interop was time and budget.  Also the c++ version will continue to exist so if we port then we have two code bases to maintain.

Comment: Those sound like valid reasons.  It's really up to you.  ***Personally*** I'd port it if it were our code, but I tend to want to port everything.  Keeping the codebase updated for us means easier maintenance work down the road.  But that doesn't sound like an issue for you, and I think you have valid reasons for just using the unmanaged version, as long as there aren't any issues with it.